# What happens to stack Frames when main() calls main()

Tags: c, program-entry-point, stack-frame

Please consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int counter=5;

    printf ("Counter = %d\n", counter);

    if (counter--)
    {
        main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc test.c -ansi -Wall –pedantic
```

Execute:

```
[root@mars home]# ./a.out 
Counter = 5
Counter = 4
Counter = 3
Counter = 2
Counter = 1
Counter = 0
```

Here main() is calling itself().

It seems that `main()` function's original stackframe will be overwritten each time `main()` is called by itself.

But what will be the return address? Can a function return to its own stackframe?

Please help me clarify this doubt.

Thanks.

Comment: `int counter` is declared `static` and therefore **not** allocated on the function's stack, but on the global heap.

Comment: apart from that, the stack isn't overwritten. Everytime the function is called a new stack is pushed, and popped again upon returning

Comment: @alk i accidently upvoted. Static variables are neither allocated in stack or heap. They are generally in data segment with distinct sections for initialized and uninitialized(BSS) ones. However, this might vary across implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** it is not overwritten. It is a normal function call (in this case recursive). You are probably confused by your `counter` variable. This variable is declared **static**, which means that it is **initialized only once**, so the line below is "executed" only once:

```
static int counter=5;
```

In other words you can think of your `counter` as if it was a global variable initialized only once (with the value 5). In each invokation of `main` it is decremented until it reaches zero. After that happens all the `main` functions return, so the stack is `unwinded` (as in normal function call which it is).

Answer (score 3):

This is quite normal in many computer languages, and is called 'recursion'. A new stack frame is created for each invocation of the function so there is no overwriting.

The return address of the outer main() is the runtime library as usual. The return address of the inner main() is the outer main().

The one thing that muddies the waters in your example is that you declared counter as static. That means it is allocated <strike>on the heap</strike> in the data segment rather than on the stack (as explained by alk in the comment), so each invocation of main() shares the same instance of counter.

Comment: Not necessarily on the heap. It's most likely just a global variable.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had a feeling heap wasn't quite right but had a mental block as I wrote that.

Comment: In fact, never on heap since heap needs to be explicitly cleared. It is part of Data segment generally with separate sections for initialized vs uninitialized values (BSS)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's a simple case of recursion. So it will allocate new stack frames & not overwrite previous frame.

Long answer:
What happens to stack Frames when **main()** calls **main()**:
C doesn't differentiate main from any other function. It's a simple, normal case of recursion.
'main' is special ONLY because, the default crt0.asm that came with the compiler (or whatever its name is in your compiler) calls main after its basic initialization (like stack pointer, etc) is done.
Apart from this difference, there is nothing, in which main is special.